# How to get the previous item of clicked listviewitem

Tags: android, listviewitem

I have two activities. In activity1 , I have list view which is populated from the database. On item click it should go to activity2. Activity2 contains two buttons (next and previous) and display the product details. In stead of "next" and "previous" button text, i was trying to get the previous item of clicked listview item and set text in button. and so for the "next" button.

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
 MyClass item = (MyClass) adapter.getItem(position-1);
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 i.putExtra("item",item.toString());
startActivity(Activity2);
}
}
```

and in activity2.class

```
 buttonprevious = (Button) findviewById(R.id.previous);
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 String preitem = b.getString("item");
 buttonprevious.setText(preitem);
```

Is this the correct way or am i doing something wrong??

How can I display product details of next and previous items??
How to use the view flipper in this case?
Thanks ..

Comment: why don't you maintain position value in an integer variable?

Comment: Code is correct but you should put both previous as ways as next in bundle.you are putting only one i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getItem(int position) method of the adapter, which return you the list item of the specified position.

(OR)

Get and Store all the database data into one static List.
Set adapter with that list.
In Activity2 access data from that list.